# placing tabs at the bottom in android

Tags: android

I am developing tab based application in android.I want to place tabs at the bottom in application.Can anyone tell how should i pursue

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 1):

In xml file try to set the Tab widgets gravity to "Bottom".